# UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Tags: java, tomcat, cpanel, virtualhost

Soy nuevo en esto y estoy configurando mi pagina web en un VPS server.

Ya le he instalado en easypache y el tomcat 7, ya puedo visualizar mi pagina de inicio, pero si trato de cargar alguna pagina jsp que tenga código java me da este error.

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Lo busque en Internet y dice lo siguiente:

> UnsupportedClassVersionError always appears when you compile "with"
>   one version (targeting one version) and execute with a previous java
>   version.
>
> JAVA_HOME does not tell the operating system where should it look for
>   the java.exe file. The operating system will take that file from the
>   PATH variable. That's why it's recommended to add at the beginning of
>   the PATH variable, the path JAVA_HOME/bin.

Por lo anterior entiendo que esta compilando con una versión mas baja y que por eso da ese problema.

Pero no se como arreglar este problema.

Alguna ayuda seria grandemente apreciada.

---

Ya pude verificar cual es la versión del JDK/JRE en mi server.

java version "1.7.0_141"

Como ya sabemos el problema es que la webaplication fue creada en neteban utilizando la version 1.8.0.131

Esto ya lo sabia perio el problema que tengo es como hacer que la version de mi servidor sea tambien 1.8.0.131.

Gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

> Por lo anterior entiendo que esta compilando con una versión mas baja y que por eso da ese problema

En realidad el problema es al revés. Por ejemplo, digamos que tu código ha sido compilado apuntando a Java 8 pero lo estás ejecutando en un JDK/JRE que apunta a Java 7 o anterior.

Te recomiendo que revises la versión del JDK/JRE que tienes instalado en tu servidor. Puedes hacerlo mediante el siguiente comando:

```
java -version
```

Luego de eso, verás un mensaje como sigue:

> java version "1.8.0_92"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

En mi caso, el equipo sobre el que trabajo tiene instalado Java 8.

Soluciones (son excluyentes):

1. Instalar la versión más reciente del JDK/JRE en tu server. Si no está disponible de manera sencilla o no tienes control directo sobre el equipo, contacta a un administrador o personal que te ayude con este mantenimiento.
2. Recompilar tu proyecto usando la misma versión (o anterior) de Java que tiene el servidor. Esto puede tener muchos problemas, sobretodo con código que no es compatible en versiones anteriores.

Recomendación: instala la versión más reciente del JDK/JRE.

Comment: Gracias Luigi. Te comento, cuando corro el comando java -version me da este error Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Pero de todas maneras me gustaria saber como instalo java 8 en el VPS

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta y publicado más información sobre las posibles soluciones. Yo te recomendaría revisar con qué versión de Java has creado el proyecto (6, 7, 8, o quizás 5 o anterior), en base a eso preguntar a tu proveedor o administrador del VPS que te ayude a instalar dicha versión de Java.

Comment: El proyecto fue creado con version 8, y debido a que es un VPS, soy yo el administrador, por eso nesecito saver como instalar o desinstalar estas versiones

Comment: Una solución más sencilla consiste en compilar para una versión específica, basta hacerlo con javac -source 1.7 para compilar tu proyecto en una ABI compatible con tu versión de java en el VPS.

Comment: Por otro lado si lo que quieres es actualizar tu versión de java, los pasos a seguir dependerán mayormente del OS instalado en el VPS, si es una versión de debian, basta con agregar repositorios de terceros para acceder a instalar el JDK8 desde apt-get, si usas archlinux, pacman es lo único que necesitas, y instalarlo con pacman -S java

Comment: @EduenSarceño la solución de compilar para una versión específica funciona siempre y cuando no se usen elementos particulares de versiones superiores de Java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza en el 90% de los casos los desarrolladores no usan las extensiones del lenguaje, así que no debe de haber problema al compilar para una versión anterior, y de haberlo, el compilador devolverá error, o bien se encargará de generar glue code dependiendo mayormente del tipo de extensión.

Comment: @EduenSarceño quisiera conocer las fuentes que respaldan tu estadística del 90% porque definitivamente estoy fuera de eso. Pero sí, es una tercer opción viable.

Comment: @LuggiMendoza El único gran cambio entre java 7 y 8 son las expresiones lambda, útiles en el cálculo lambda https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java8lambdas/, no obstante los usuarios que usan estas características son una minoría, puesto que tienen una curva extra de aprendizaje, y en equipos de desarrollo el código debe ser escrito de tal forma que la mayoría de los usuarios lo entiendan sin necesidad de consultar fuentes esotéricas.  Últimamente se han vuelto populares como sustito a las clases anónimas, pero ningún proyecto serio las usa ya que se prefiere backward compatibility.

Comment: @EduenSarceño en realidad hay muchos más cambios en Java 8 que lambdas. Fuera de eso, parece más opinión tuya que hechos o números concretos. Gracias por la información, de todos modos.